# undefined method `mount_uploader' for Category:Class Mongoid Nginx Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, mongoid, passenger, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave in my application. The problem is it works well in development mode. But when deploying to nginx with passenger it throws the following error:

```
/home/webserver/raw/releases/20110919033346/app/models/category.rb:11: undefined method `mount_uploader' for Category:Class (NoMethodError)
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load_file'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `load_file'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in `require_or_load'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `depend_on'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/rails/mongoid.rb:55:in `load_model'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/rails/mongoid.rb:18:in `load_models'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/rails/mongoid.rb:17:in `each'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/rails/mongoid.rb:17:in `load_models'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/paths.rb:102:in `each'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/paths.rb:102:in `each'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/rails/mongoid.rb:16:in `load_models'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:88:in `_callback_before_5'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:420:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:40:in `initialize'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `new'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `build'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `build'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:209:in `inject'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `each'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `inject'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `build'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:162:in `build_middleware_stack'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:35
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /home/webserver/raw/releases/20110919033346/config/environment.rb:5
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:22
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

Here is my gem list

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.9, 3.0.7)
actionpack (3.0.9, 3.0.7)
activemodel (3.0.9, 3.0.7)
activerecord (3.0.9, 3.0.7)
activeresource (3.0.9, 3.0.7)
activesupport (3.1.0, 3.0.9, 3.0.7)
akami (1.0.0)
arel (2.0.10)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.0)
bson (1.3.1)
bson_ext (1.3.1)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.0.13)
carrierwave (0.5.7, 0.5.6, 0.5.4)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
erubis (2.6.6)
escape (0.0.4)
exception_notification_rails3 (1.2.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gyoku (0.4.4)
httpi (0.9.5, 0.9.4)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
mini_magick (3.3, 3.2.1)
mongo (1.3.1)
mongoid (2.0.1)
multi_json (1.0.3)
nokogiri (1.5.0, 1.4.4)
nori (1.0.2, 0.2.2)
passenger (3.0.7)
polyglot (0.3.2, 0.3.1)
pr_geohash (1.0.0)
pyu-ntlm-http (0.1.3.1)
rack (1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.9, 3.0.7)
railties (3.0.9, 3.0.7)
rake (0.9.2, 0.9.0)
rdoc (3.9.4, 3.8)
rmagick (2.13.1)
rsolr (0.12.1)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
savon (0.9.7, 0.9.6, 0.9.2)
subexec (0.1.0, 0.0.4)
sunspot (1.2.1)
sunspot_rails_mongoid (1.2.1)
SystemTimer (1.2.3)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.10, 1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.29, 0.3.27)
wasabi (2.0.0)
will_paginate (3.0.0, 3.0.pre4, 3.0.pre2)
```

The ruby version is `ruby 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.02`

Please, could give any idea about this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you installed imagemagick binaries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the the same / a similar problem. In my case, it was something silly. In my Gemfile, I just referenced the gem, but you need to require the mongoid extension. So your line in the Gemfile should look like this:

```
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
```